# paypal sandbox to live in ios

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal Sdk(https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) in my iPhone app.I  was successfully integrated and tested in sandbox mode. I have given client for production in appdlegate file.I changed the environment to "PayPalEnvironmentProduction". I have some doubts regarding while changing to live.

```
    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                     PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
```

1. what is the use of "endpoint" and "secret" in my app credentials (because i used Only client id)
2. shall i need to submit the app to paypal to get any other credentials from paypal or directly to Appstore
3. will my app is approved by apple if  i use paypal
4. what is the use of below code (even though i removed code )payment process is working

   ```
     _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];

     _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;

     _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";

    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"Awesome Shirts, Inc.";

    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];

    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];
   ```

If it is necessary to submit the app to paypal first what are the necessary steps to taken and any detailed expalanation may be helpful.what is difference between paypalSdk and MPL, which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

> 1 what is the use of "endpoint" and "secret" in my app credentials (because i used Only client id)

Client id is the only credential that you need to use with the PayPal iOS SDK.

> 2 shall i need to submit the app to paypal to get any other credentials from paypal or directly to Appstore

No.

> 3 will my app is approved by apple if i use paypal

Many apps using the PayPal iOS SDK have already been approved by Apple.

> 4 what is the use of below code (even though i removed code )payment process is working

This is all explained in the documentation and the header files.

> If it is necessary to submit the app to paypal first what are the necessary steps to taken

It is not necessary to submit your app to PayPal.

> any detailed expalanation may be helpful.what is difference between paypalSdk and MPL, which is better?

The PayPal iOS SDK is the one which we will continue to support into the future. The only reason to use the older MPL library is if you need features which are not yet supported in the PayPal iOS SDK and the REST APIs on which it relies.

Comment: Also, is there any payback(refund to user account from merchant account) option in paypal ios sdk

Comment: @siva Refunds are not handled within the PayPal iOS SDK. Refund requests would be made from your server.

Comment: @ Dave Thankyou,let me know is there any guide to do refund

Comment: @siva the documentation for the PayPal REST APIs is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/). You can find information there regarding refunds and many other topics.